# how to setup npm environment variables in windows

Tags: node.js, npm, private

i have a  Windows machine. i need to setup the npm private profile to accept private packages for my  code.  my dev team has provided only a hexadecimal token  for the setup.
   The npm documentation describes to use the token like this
export NPM_TOKEN="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000". but windows machine  is not accepting this command.

can anyone  help me on setting the  npm  token in a windows 10 laptop.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this:

- In Windows search bar: Start typing something like `variables` or `environment var` and click on the `Edit environment variables for your account` entry
- In the opened window click on `New...` button in `User variables` section.
- Variable name: `NPM_TOKEN`
- Variable value: `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` *(use your own token)*
- Save and restart computer

It should be done

Comment: I think it's "edit the system environment variables" on windows 10. That should pull up the system properties dialog, and under the advanced tab you'll see environment variables there.

Comment: I can't believe I searched for an hour to find this. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Another method

In PowerShell, you can set environment variable by `$env:path=value`.
This will be applicable only to that Powershell session only.